Bash multi-ping script has empty variables if ran under crontab
I scraped together a bash script to do multi-ping logging on Centos/Debian, when run from console it works fine, but run under crontab, the variable $NUM is left blank which should be a number such as 02 or 03, which lets the script find the IP address to ping from the config file.
More info: The goal is to provide bare basic ping data to an ISP that refuses to recognize advanced tools like MTR or router logs/graphs for troubleshooting. The ISP is having packet loss on several circuits, and they check it and say "looks good to us", they recognize ping data as a valid troubleshooting tool, so my ping script saves ping data in 10 minute increments to timestamped files, then another script sorts those files for any high latency or packet loss, which I send to the ISP as proof that the failure is inside their network. I have a backup ISP that I also log at the same time as proof that the destinations are generally available via other providers. My scripting skills are not fantastic, so I definitely consider any improvements.
Script has 2 components, a cfg file:
### Main program variables:
SPOOLDIR="/var/spool/pingstats"
BADPINGSDIR="/tmp/badpings"
BADPINGLOG="$BADPINGSDIR/badpings.log"
PINGLOG="$PROGRAMDIR/ping.log"

##### Set NODE NAMES (its just a name), host can be IP or hostname ie abc.com and maxping latency thresholds (edit/add nodes as needed)
NODENAME01=router
HOST01=10.0.0.1
MAXPING01=5

NODENAME02=dns1
HOST02=68.6.16.30
MAXPING02=35

NODENAME03=dns2
HOST03=1.1.1.1
MAXPING03=35

NODENAME04=fibergw
HOST04=77.77.77.74
MAXPING04=10

## Several more....

The script:
#!/bin/bash

## Base variables
PROGRAMDIR="/root/pingstats"
PINGCONF="$PROGRAMDIR/PingConfig.cfg"
TIMESTAMP="$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)"
TIMESTAMP2() {
  date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S" # current time
}

source $PINGCONF

## check dir structure:
if [ ! -d $SPOOLDIR ]; then
        mkdir $SPOOLDIR
fi

## Loop through each nodename listed in cfg
for n in `grep NODENAME $PINGCONF`
        do
        echo "Processing Node: $n"
        echo "$(TIMESTAMP2) : Processing Node: $n" >> $PINGLOG
#### The next couple of lines are the problem, because $NUM ends up blank via cron
        NUM=$(grep -oE '[N]ODENAME.{,2}' <<< "$n" | grep -o '[0-9]\+')
        echo "Node number for $n is $NUM" >> $PINGLOG
        HOSTTMP=HOST$NUM
        HOSTIP=${!HOSTTMP}
        echo "NODE is $n and HOSTIP is $HOSTIP"
        if [ ! -d "$SPOOLDIR/$NODENAME" ]; then
                mkdir "$SPOOLDIR/$NODENAME"
        fi
        echo "$(TIMESTAMP2) : Pinging NODE: $NODENAME at $HOSTIP logging to file:
        $SPOOLDIR/$NODENAME/$TIMESTAMP" >> $PINGLOG

        echo " Starting ping to $HOSTIP"
        ping -i 2 -s 8000 -c 300 $HOSTIP > "$SPOOLDIR/$NODENAME/$TIMESTAMP" &

        sleep 1
done


Expected to see several processes to be running pings. The logging shows me this:
2024-09-05_13:08:03 : Processing Node: NODENAME02=dns1
Node number for NODENAME02=dns1 is
2024-09-05_13:08:03 : Pinging NODE:  at  logging to file:
        /var/spool/pingstats//202409051308


There is a blank after the is and at, which should show $NUM and $HOSTIP, which was found via nested var $HOST$NUM
My /etc/crontab is:
*/10 * * * * root /root/pingstats/ping-nodes


Successful run from console spawns several processes such as:
 ps aux | grep ping
root     14533  0.0  0.1   1952   580 pts/8    S    13:19   0:00 ping -i 2 -s 8000 -c 300 10.0.0.1
root     14550  0.0  0.1   1952   584 pts/8    S    13:19   0:00 ping -i 2 -s 8000 -c 300 68.6.16.30
root     14560  0.0  0.1   1952   580 pts/8    S    13:19   0:00 ping -i 2 -s 8000 -c 300 1.1.1.1
root     14570  0.0  0.1   1952   580 pts/8    S    13:19   0:00 ping -i 2 -s 8000 -c 300 77.77.77.74



Have a look at https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/multiping.sh.txt and https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/netfunc.bash.txt

Remove ! from ${!HOSTTMP}?

If you sourced the file already there's no need to read it, just use the vars, or much better define an array.

@SmplJohn – What does the Processing Node: $n logging show?

@Cyrus Why should they remove that? It's the correct syntax for indirect variable expansion.

Why do you write [N]ODENAME instead of jost NODENAME in your grep patterns?

There is good info here cron_info . It's too bad it's not redilly visible when users select the [tag:cron] tag

@Barmar: Perhaps I misunderstood the code of SmplJohn.

@Cyrus They're using HOSTTMP=HOST$NUM to construct the name of a variable that was assigned during source $PINGCONF, then getting the value of that variable.

@F.Hauri Felix, your work looks very impressive, that is a very useful tool that I will use, the plotting function does not work on Debian 12.5 (line 303: echo: write error: Broken pipe), and pinging 6 hosts for an hour fails to exit properly pressing q. My goal here is to provide evidence to an ISP of their poor network quality, they will not recognize advanced tools like this or MTR as valid data for troubleshooting. So my poor shell script saves ping output to files that I can send to the ISP after sorting for packet loss.

@SmplJohn For plotting, this require gnuplot to be installed and of course an access to valid $DISPLAY (I'm using debian too;-).

I ran this on my raspberry pi 4: ./multiping.sh -pci .6666 {dns,www}.google.com {ftp.us,www}.debian.org www.stack{exchange,overflow}.com, (6 targets)  let run over ~ 90 minutes, then hit q key (all ping was stopped immediately, verified from other terminal), then quietly wait 21 minutes to see all data to be plotted by gnuplot, then 2 more minutes utils the script finish by himself.  I agree: This is not perfect, but q will terminate script properly.

... But without p, not trying to use gnuplot, q will quit near instantaneously.

@SmplJohn I've found the reason my script take time to quit. Bug corrected! Thanks!

Simply by sourcing your PingConfig.cfg
If you're confident with content of $PINGCONF, you could source them. (Care, this will execute commands, if present in your config file!)
Notes:

I use printf '%(date format string)T' instead of fork to date, for date time print.
I use indirection to build numbered variables

#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob

PROGRAMDIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
PINGCONF="$PROGRAMDIR/PingConfig.cfg"
printf -v TIMESTAMP '%(%Y%m%d%H%M)T' -1

. "$PINGCONF"

for nodename in ${!NODENAME*}; do
    host=HOST${nodename//*([A-Z])} maxping=MAXPING${nodename//*([A-Z])}
    printf 'Processing Node: %d: "%s"\n' ${nodename//*([A-Z])} "${!nodename}"
    if [ ! -d "$SPOOLDIR/${!nodename}" ]; then
        mkdir -p "$SPOOLDIR/${!nodename}"
    fi
    printf >>$PINGLOG \
        '%(%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)T: Pinging NODE: %s at %s logging to file: %s\n' \
        -1 "${!nodename}" "${!host}" "$SPOOLDIR/${!nodename}/$TIMESTAMP" 

    echo " Starting ping to ${!host}"
    ping -i 2 -s 8000 -c ${!maxping} ${!host} \
        >"$SPOOLDIR/${!nodename}/$TIMESTAMP" &
    sleep .2
done

Processing Node: 1: "router"
 Starting ping to 10.0.0.1
Processing Node: 2: "dns1"
 Starting ping to 68.6.16.30
Processing Node: 3: "dns2"
 Starting ping to 1.1.1.1
Processing Node: 4: "fibergw"
 Starting ping to 77.77.77.74

$ cat ping.log 
2024-09-05_16:24:03: Pinging NODE: router at 10.0.0.1 logging to file: /tmp/so/pingstats/router/202409051624
2024-09-05_16:24:03: Pinging NODE: dns1 at 68.6.16.30 logging to file: /tmp/so/pingstats/dns1/202409051624
2024-09-05_16:24:03: Pinging NODE: dns2 at 1.1.1.1 logging to file: /tmp/so/pingstats/dns2/202409051624
2024-09-05_16:24:03: Pinging NODE: fibergw at 77.77.77.74 logging to file: /tmp/so/pingstats/fibergw/202409051624

$ ls -gR ping*
-rw-r--r-- 1 user  434  5 sep 16:24 ping.log

pingstats:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 user 4096  5 sep 16:24 dns1
drwxr-xr-x 2 user 4096  5 sep 16:24 dns2
drwxr-xr-x 2 user 4096  5 sep 16:24 fibergw
drwxr-xr-x 2 user 4096  5 sep 16:24 router

pingstats/dns1:
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 159  5 sep 16:25 202409051624

pingstats/dns2:
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 150  5 sep 16:25 202409051624

pingstats/fibergw:
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 162  5 sep 16:24 202409051624

pingstats/router:
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 151  5 sep 16:24 202409051624

Your PingConfig.cfg could be edited by others?
If so, it could be dangerous to source them! For this, you have to parse them line by line, avoid dangerous character, sanitize your values before defining variables:
#!/bin/bash

PROGRAMDIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
PINGCONF="$PROGRAMDIR/PingConfig.cfg"
MAXPINGDEFAULT=10
printf -v TIMESTAMP '%(%Y%m%d%H%M)T' -1

progName=${0##*/} ; die() { echo >&2 "$progName ERROR: $*";exit 1;}

nodIdxs=()
while read -r line; do
    case $line in *[#\;\`\)\}\(\{]* ) continue;; esac # Skip comment'n bad lines
    IFS== read -r fld val <<<"$line"
    num=${fld//[!0-9]}
    if [[ $num ]]; then
        if ! [[ -v nodIdxs[10#$num] ]]; then
            nodIdxs[10#$num]=$num
            declare -A node_$num
        fi
        fld=${fld%$num}
        case $fld in
            NODENAME ) case ${val,,} in *[!a-z0-9-]* )
                    die "Host name not valid: $fld$num = '$val'";; esac ;;
            HOST ) msg="Host IP not valid: "; case ${val,,} in *[!0-9.]* )
                    die "$msg$fld$num = '$val'";; esac
               read -ra _a <<<"${val//./ }"
               (( ${#_a[@]} == 4 )) || die "$msg$fld$num = '$val'"
               for _i in "${_a[@]}"; do
                (( _i == ( _i & 255 ) )) || die "$msg$fld$num = '$val'"
               done ;;

            MAXPING ) case ${val,,} in *[!0-9]* )
                    die "MaxPing not integer: $fld$num = '$val'";; esac ;;
            * ) die "Option '$fld' ($num) unknown" ;;
        esac
        printf -v node_$num[$fld] %s $val
    elif [[ $val ]]; then
        val=${val//\"}
        val=${val/\$BADPINGSDIR/$BADPINGSDIR}
        val=${val/\$PROGRAMDIR/$PROGRAMDIR}
        declare "$fld=$val";
    fi
done < "$PINGCONF"

# declare -p BADPINGLOG BADPINGSDIR PINGLOG SPOOLDIR ${!node_*} ; exit # Uncomment for test parsing.

for crtNode in ${nodIdxs[@]}; do
    declare -n thisNode=node_$crtNode
    ! [[ -v thisNode[NODENAME] ]] && echo "Nodename missing for $crtNode, skip!" && continue
    ! [[ -v thisNode[HOST] ]] && echo "Host IP missing for $crtNode, skip!" && continue
    printf 'Processing Node: %d: "%s"\n' ${crtNode#*_} "${thisNode[NODENAME]}"
    if [ ! -d "$SPOOLDIR/${thisNode[NODENAME]}" ]; then
        mkdir -p "$SPOOLDIR/${thisNode[NODENAME]}"
    fi
    printf '%(%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)T: Pinging NODE: %s at %s logging to file: %s\n' \
           -1 "${thisNode[NODENAME]}" "${thisNode[HOST]}" \
           "$SPOOLDIR/${thisNode[NODENAME]}/$TIMESTAMP" >>$PINGLOG

    echo " Starting ping to ${thisNode[HOST]}"
    ping -i 2 -s 8000 -c ${thisNode[MAXPING]:-$MAXPINGDEFAULT} ${thisNode[HOST]} \
         > "$SPOOLDIR/${thisNode[NODENAME]}/$TIMESTAMP" &
    sleep .2
done

Disclaimer!
This script is not well tested, against bad config files! If really publicly accessible config file you may have to

Copy config file somewhere not publicly accessible before
testing this file with file for ensuring they contain only ASCII text
search for bad characters using something like LANG=C grep -q '[^a-z0-9A-Z="$._-]' && die ...


Thanks for everyone's patience, I did some revisions and cleanup and came up with this working method that works the same on console or crontab:
Ping.cfg file (used in a few other scripts)
### Main program variables, suggested to leave these
SPOOLDIR="/var/spool/pingstats"
BADPINGSDIR="/tmp/badpings"
BADPINGLOG="$BADPINGSDIR/badpings.log"
PINGLOG="$PROGRAMDIR/ping.log"

### Set your email prefs:
CLIENT="ACME Inc"
ADMINEMAIL="jim@home.com"
SENDEMAIL=yes

##### Set list of nodes to ping with 3 criteria: name, IP/hostname, and max latency in milliseconds.

NODE01="router,10.0.0.1,10"
NODE02="dns1,68.6.16.30,35"
NODE03="dns2,1.1.1.1,35"
NODE04="fibergw,7.7.7.4,10"
NODE05="cablegw,6.2.1.5,10"
## Several more...

Script:
#!/bin/bash
##   Schedule in /etc/crontab every 10 minutes:
##   */10 * * * * root /root/pingstats/ping-nodes
##   Edit Ping.cfg with as many hosts as needed.
#################################################

## More vars:
scripts out of the /root dir
PROGRAMDIR="/root/pingstats"
PINGCONF="$PROGRAMDIR/Ping.cfg"
TIMESTAMP="$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)"
TIMESTAMP2() {
  date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S" # current time
}

source $PINGCONF
## check dir structure:
if [ ! -d $SPOOLDIR ]; then
        mkdir $SPOOLDIR
fi

## Loop through each nodename variable listed in cfg file:
while read -r NODENAME HOSTIP rest; do
    printf 'Nodename is %s and hostip is %s\n' "$NODENAME" "$HOSTIP"
    if [ ! -d "$SPOOLDIR/$NODENAME" ]; then
                mkdir "$SPOOLDIR/$NODENAME"
    fi
    echo "$(TIMESTAMP2) : Pinging NODE: $NODENAME at $HOSTIP logging to file: $SPOOLDIR/$NODENAME/$TIMESTAMP" >> $PINGLOG
    echo " Starting ping to $HOSTIP logging to file: $SPOOLDIR/$NODENAME/$TIMESTAMP"
    ping -i 2 -s 8000 -c 300 $HOSTIP > "$SPOOLDIR/$NODENAME/$TIMESTAMP" &
    sleep 1
        echo ""; echo "" >> $PINGLOG
done < <(awk -F'[",]' '/^NODE/{print $2, $3}' $PINGCONF)

Sorry if my code isn't great, I have written ~5000 lines of bash over the last 20 years, I'm probably 6/10 on expertise.

Once your config file sourced, there is no need to re-read them with awk.
